# Caused by: org.gradle.cache.LockTimeoutException

Tags: android, gradle, caching

Caused by: org.gradle.cache.LockTimeoutException: Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (C:\Users\ MyApp\ .gradle\caches\5.6.4\fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.

**Some times I got this error.**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not create service of type FileHasher using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createCachingFileHasher().

  > Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (C:\Users\MyApp\ .gradle\caches\5.6.4\fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
  >   Owner PID: 15416
  >   Our PID: 528
  >   Owner Operation: 
  >   Our operation: 
  >   Lock file: C:\Users\MApp\ .gradle\caches\5.6.4\fileHashes\fileHashes.lock
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s

Comment: How did you fix this .Please share the solution

Comment: clear your temprory file
Run -> %temp% -> delete all.
-------------------
Restart Android studio -> Clear -> Build Gradle